Git Credential Manager raises a FileLoadException making git unusable
Background is my computer crashed (core dumped), since it has restarted I have been unable to use git.
I was previously logged into git and the GitHub CLI, but after the crash when running git commands an exception would be raised.
I removed Git, removed the GitHub CLI and all credentials saved on the computer and started from scratch but I still have the same issue.
I tried running git auth logout and then git auth login but was unsuccessful.
I have seen this GitHub issue and, added git-credential-manager-core to my exclusions but this did not fix it.
Any command I try to run of the form git credential-manager ... will raise the same exception below but also show an error saying The exception unknown software exception (0xe0434352) occurred in the application at 0x000000007666B282.
The exception trace is shown below:
PS C:\Users\Admin> gh auth login
? Where do you use GitHub? GitHub.com
? What is your preferred protocol for Git operations on this host? HTTPS
? Authenticate Git with your GitHub credentials? Yes
? How would you like to authenticate GitHub CLI? Login with a web browser

! First copy your one-time code: ****-****
Press Enter to open github.com in your browser...
✓ Authentication complete.
- gh config set -h github.com git_protocol https
✓ Configured git protocol
✓ Logged in as <anonymized-username>
! You were already logged in to this account
PS C:\Users\Admin> cd C:\Users\Admin\ProjectDirectory
PS C:\Users\Admin\ProjectDirectory> git fetch --prune

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: A procedure imported by 'System.CommandLine, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.
   at GitCredentialManager.Application..ctor(ICommandContext context, IHostProviderRegistry providerRegistry, IConfigurationService configurationService)
   at GitCredentialManager.Application..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   at GitCredentialManager.Program.AppMain(Object o)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Object obj)
Username for 'https://github.com': <anonymized-username>
Password for 'https://<anonymized-username>@github.com':

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: A procedure imported by 'System.CommandLine, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.
   at GitCredentialManager.Application..ctor(ICommandContext context, IHostProviderRegistry providerRegistry, IConfigurationService configurationService)
   at GitCredentialManager.Application..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   at GitCredentialManager.Program.AppMain(Object o)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Object obj)
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/<anonymized-username>/hidden-repo-name.git/'

I presume something is corrupted, but I am unsure what/how to fix it. Any advice would be appreciated.
